# node-7z and xml2json conflict

Tags: javascript, node.js, 7zip, xml-to-json

in node.js,
I have problem when import both packages (node-7z and xml2json), 
I have some function **that no one calls it** ("dummy"),

```
    import { extractFull } from 'node-7z'
    const xml2json = require('xml2json');

    function dummy(){
        const myStream = extractFull('./zip/myfile.7z', './unzipped/')

    }
```

and I get the following error

```
C:\projects\nodeTests\node_modules\joi\lib\types\object\index.js:445
source-map-support.js:445
        Hoek.assert(isRegExp || pattern instanceof Any, 'pattern must be a regex or schema');
             ^
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: pattern must be a regex or schema
source-map-support.js:448
    at internals.Object.pattern (C:\projects\nodeTests\node_modules\joi\lib\types\object\index.js:445:14)
    at Object.internals.root (C:\projects\nodeTests\node_modules\joi\lib\index.js:432:34)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\nodeTests\node_modules\joi\lib\index.js:447:28)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\projects\nodeTests\node_modules\xml2json\lib\xml2json.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

*if I comment the code inside "dummy" function I dont get any error 
*if I comment the line of require "xml2json" I dont get any error

why I have this problem and why how does the code in "dummy" function affect me if no one calls this function?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*https://github.com/quentinrossetti/node-7z*  according to this link you shoud pass an object with extractFull function for example

```
import Seven from 'node-7z'
const myStream = Seven.extractFull('./archive.7z', './output/dir/', { 
  $progress: true
});
```

Comment: yes I know, same error there.. the strange thing is that no one call this function and still I get this error.. if I comment the code inside OR if I comment the require of xml2json there is NO error

Comment: try to add semi clone after the statement

Comment: its work fine in my computer see  https://www.dropbox.com/s/5g8pxcys3r1zxa9/shot-2019-06-12-20-25-55.png?dl=0

Comment: I use typescript, can you please check it with ts file?